# Compare File TimeStamps in 2 directories

Tags: unix, timestamp

I've got mirror sites of code @ 2 locations:

testing & operations

They are each just folders with C# projects in them. I want to make sure that testing always has the latest files, i.e. if operations has a more recent version of a file than testing, then output the stale file to a list.

**Concrete Example:**

testing has 2 files:
file1 & file2

operations has 2 files: file2 & file3

operations has a newer file2 than testing, so output "file2" to a new text file.

How can I do this in Unix?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

If your Unix system has [`rsync`](http://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html), you can combine the `--dry-run` and `--testing` options to tell you what you want to know, I think.

```
rsync --dry-run --update -aH operations/. testing/.
```

(Note: For your example, this would also show `file3`, since it exists in operations but not testing...)

Comment: Sorry to hear that...  Well, it would not be too hard to whip up a Perl script to do this.  Maybe try asking on serverfault.com?